# get Visual Studio to use latest CSS/SASS when validating SASS code (@use)

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, sass

I'm trying to rewrite my SASS files replacing @import with @use, but Visual Studio doesn't think @use is a valid directive according to CSS 4.0.

Is there a way to update to the latest version supporting all SASS syntax?

```
@use "..\\Shared\\Config" as config;
@use "..\\Shared\\Function" as func;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try node-sass and run watch:sass command to compile scss or you can update your live sass extension and dart sass to new version.
You can check this [site](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.live-sass) for new update

and after you click install it alert that do you want to open on vs code if you click yes it open vs code for you and you see this message :

This extension is deprecated. Use the New Live Sass Compiler extension instead.
and you have to click on New Live Sass link and then you can install it and use it :)